# React State Object Input Can't use Trim

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I want to use trim on my input which works for normal state but object state it doesn't example below will show it clearly:

This works:

```
onChangeText={(name) =>    
                  this.setState({ user: name.trim() })
                }
```

This doesn't work and this I need help with:

```
onChangeText={(name) =>    
                  this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, name.trim() } })
                }
```

Here trim can't be used, setstate works and gets name but it doesn't get it trimmed, it even throws error that I can't use trim so how to use it in a nested state?

Comment: Try this : 

`onChangeText={(name) =>    
                  this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user,name: name.trim() } })
                }`

For object, you should provide key-value pairs. you have provided the value but there is no key to hold that value. You can replace `name` key with your actual states key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand what is `user`? Is it an `object`? or is it a `string`?

Your first code sample is expecting `user` to be a `string` while your second code example expecting `user` to be an `object`.

Since example one is working, I will leave it aside and show how to make second example work.

When you're trying to assign the value, you're missing `properties`, it should be `name: name.trim()`

```js
onChangeText={(name) =>    
  this.setState({ user: { ...this.state.user, name: name.trim() } }) // <<== missing properties
}
```

Now if you wish to read the value, you can refer as below

```js
render() {
  return (
    <Text>{this.state.user.name}</Text>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank u! This seems to be working! But I wouldn't say I miss properties, isnt it when you write name it's the same as name:name? Isn't that sth about Es6 or Es5? Also yes I agree it's expected that user is object but just name itself does work, without writing name:name exactly cause I'd say it still IS a property. It's just that this shorter sintax can't use trim()

Comment: @Helpwotjjs: The shorter syntax works only if `properties` on the left is exactly the same as the `variable` on the right, for example `name: name`, then yes you can apply the shorthand syntax. But in your case it is `name: name.trim()`, it is obviously that left and right is not 100% the same right? And hence you cant apply shorthand syntax